# How is a dynamically sized FIFO implemented in verilog

Tags: dynamic, verilog, fifo

Say I would want to have a FIFO that does something like this:

```
local_max_fifo local_max_save
(
    .clk (clk),
    .rst (rst),
    .din (local_max_in),
    .dout (local_max_out),
    .wr_en (local_max_write_data),
    .rd_en (local_max_read_data)
);
```

Is there a way to do this so that all FIFOs in the project use the same fixed size memory pool? So I might have 10 FIFOs in my project but all 10 FIFOs use the same memory pool

Comment: Do you want *parameterized* depth of FIFOs?

Comment: If that makes sense depends on a number of design specific parameters, e.g. can data be written and read each cycle, is variable latency for read or write acceptable, what is the data size, what amount of overhead is acceptable, etc.  Disadvantage of a shared pool is the overhead, and limited number of ports on the physical memories so read/write for some FIFOs may have to wait until others are finished.  So in the end, this is not so much a question about design using Verilog, but more a question about architecture.

Comment: by same memory pool, do you mean a big memory divided equally among 10Fifos in your case?

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is hardware malloc. I began thinking of ideas where I keep an array that says which blocks have been allocated and divide shared memory into blocks and when a FIFO fills its buffer it is allocated more space. If i have 2^16 32 bit words, then I can divide it up into 64 blocks and use a 64 bit array for saying whether a block is allocated or not.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear enough, at least to my understanding.

If what you are trying to accomplish is to use the same physical resource ( "THE FIFO" ) for 10 different computations you could use multiplexing, knowing that any data coming from the unselected channels will be lost. If that is what you are trying to do; using a control line with multiplexors should allow you to use the same physical FIFO. I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This does not provide a solution, it should be a comment. You'll be able to comment when you reach a reputation of 10.